# Store data in an array from a loop

Tags: python, arrays, raw-input

I have two set of datas which I would like to multiply one by each other, and store the result in an array for each value.

For now I have this:

```
import csv
from mpdaf.obj import Spectrum, WaveCoord
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
from csv import reader


file_path = input("Enter full transmission curve path : ")
with open(file_path, 'rw') as f:
    data = list(reader(f, delimiter=","))
    wavelength = [i[0] for i in data]
    percentage = [float(str(i[1]).replace(',','.')) for i in data]

spectrum = input("Full spectrum path : ")
spe = Spectrum(filename=spectrum, ext=0)
data_flux = spe.data

flux_array = []

for i in percentage:
    for j in data_flux:
        flux = i*j
        flux_array.append(flux)

print(flux_array)
```

Like this it take the first `i` then multiply it by all the `j` then takes the next `i` etc etc ...
I would like to just multiply the first `i` by the first `j`, then store the value in the array, then multiply the 2nd `i` by the second `j` and store the value etc ...

Comment: I think `flux = i * j` should do instead of `flux = percentage[i]*data_flux[j]`

Comment: you can't use float as list index - ie. `list[3.14]` - it has to be integer number - `list[3]`

Comment: `i` and `j` are not integers, but the elements of `percentage` and `data_flux`, you are trying to access  the value at an index that is not an integer. If you want to refer to the object at current index of loop, simply use `i*j`

Answer (score 2):

It is as the error message says: your indices `i` and `j` are floats, not integers. When you write `for i in percentage:`, `i` takes on every value in the `percentage` list. Instead, you might want to iterate through a range. Here's an example to illustrate the difference:

```py
percentage = [50.0, 60.0, 70.0]
for i in percentage:
    print(i)
    # 50.0
    # 60.0
    # 70.0

for i in range(len(percentage)):
    print(i)
    # 0
    # 1
    # 2
```

To iterate through a list of indices, you probably want to iterate through a range:

```py
for i in range(len(percentage)):
    for j in range(len(data_flux)):
        flux = percentage[i]*data_flux[j]
        flux_array.append(flux)
```

This will iterate through the integers of each list, starting at 0 and ending at the maximum index of the list.

Comment: Oh yes indeed, I must be tired to not have seen that ! Thank you !

Just a little question about a doubt I have here also, here with 2 loops I multiply ````i```` by all the ```j```, then next ````i```` by all the ````j````  etc...while I want to multiply each ```i``` by each ```j```

Comment: @Geo573 - your 2 loops finally gives you `multiply each i by each j`

Comment: Actually, the array i get has a len of: ```len(flux_array) = 13549761``` while it should be 3681 as ```percentage``` and ```data_flux``` both make 3681, why so ?